# Does R randomForest behave the same on variables from numeric and integer classes?

Tags: r, class, random-forest

Does R random forest algorithm implemented in randomForest package behaves the same on variables from numeric and integer classes ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes the randomForest implementation does treat integers and numerics(doubles) alike. Feature values, in the eyes of a RF model, can only be equal/higher or lower than a given break point, thus it do no matters if the numbers originally were integers or doubles.

- randomForest do have an exception for factors (in contrary to sklearn.randomForest which even treats factors as numerics)

*citing from source code: randomForest/R/randomForest.default.R -line 60*

```
if (is.data.frame(x)) {
        xlevels <- lapply(x, mylevels) 
        ncat <- sapply(xlevels, length)
        ## Treat ordered factors as numerics.
        ncat <- ifelse(sapply(x, is.ordered), 1, ncat)
        x <- data.matrix(x)
...
}
```

*mylevels is defined in defined in line 2*

```
## mylevels() returns levels if given a factor, otherwise 0.
mylevels <- function(x) if (is.factor(x)) levels(x) else 0
```

- Thus xlevels record levels/categories if a given feature column in x is.factor, otherwise 0. In low level C++, if xlevels is 0, the feature column is treated as numeric, otherwise as factor. When converting x to a data.matrix all features are converted to numerics.

Citing from line *194*

```
    storage.mode(x) <- "double"
```

Here x the storage mode of x is set to double

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether there's any difference in how the implementation of the algorithm works on numeric vs. integer data, but you could check empirically for differences in output. For example, create two random forest models with the same data, but with integer columns coded as numeric in one case and integer in the other. Here's an illustration with the built-in `mtcars` data frame (for which all the columns are initially `numeric` class):

```
library(randomForest)
library(dplyr)

rf1 = replicate(1000, randomForest(mpg ~ hp + cyl + wt + disp + am + qsec + drat, 
                                              data=mtcars), simplify=FALSE)

rf2 = replicate(1000, randomForest(mpg ~ hp + cyl + wt + disp + am + qsec + drat, 
                                        data=mtcars %>% mutate(cyl=as.integer(cyl), 
                                                               am=as.integer(am))), 
                simplify=FALSE)
```

Now compare the results and note they look about the same:

```
mean(sapply(rf1, function(x) x[["mse"]]))
[1] 5.942344
mean(sapply(rf2, function(x) x[["mse"]]))
[1] 5.924892

sd(sapply(rf1, function(x) x[["mse"]]))
[1] 1.035155
sd(sapply(rf2, function(x) x[["mse"]]))
[1] 1.038043

mean(sapply(rf1, function(x) importance(x)[rownames(importance(x))=="cyl"]))
[1] 183.1852
mean(sapply(rf2, function(x) importance(x)[rownames(importance(x))=="cyl"]))
[1] 183.2401

sd(sapply(rf1, function(x) importance(x)[rownames(importance(x))=="cyl"]))
[1] 14.06802
sd(sapply(rf2, function(x) importance(x)[rownames(importance(x))=="cyl"]))
[1] 14.04218
```

Of course you can do additional checks to make sure the behavior is the same in any way that's important for your situation and you'll also want to check whether the behavior is the same for classification as well as for regression.